# How to understand returning values from recursive function calls?

Tags: javascript, recursion, maze

I am trying to recursively solve a maze using Javascript, how do I return my solution from my recursive function call?

I am attempting to create a maze solver algorithm using recursion, in Javascript. My maze shall follow the following pattern:

```
let rawMaze = 
    [
      [0, 1, 3], 
      [0, 1, 0], 
      [2, 1, 0]
    ],
```

Where

```
0: wall
1: valid path
2: start
3: end
```

I create an object from the source array,

```
let maze = []
constructMaze() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      maze[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        const Cell = {
          x: j,
          y: i,
          state: rawMaze[i][j],
          id: uniqueId()
        };
        this.maze[i].push(Cell);
      }
    }
    console.table(this.maze);
  }
```

I also use a helper function to get the neighbours of any given cell,

```
getNeighbours(x, y) {
    let maze = this.maze;
    let neighbours = [];
    maze.forEach(row => {
      row.forEach(cell => {
        if (
          (cell.x == x && cell.y == y + 1) ||
          (cell.x == x && cell.y == y - 1) ||
          (cell.y == y && cell.x == x + 1) ||
          (cell.y == y && cell.x == x - 1)
        ) {
          neighbours.push(cell);
        }
      });
    });

    return neighbours;
  }
```

The main logic happens in my checkNeighbours function, where I determine the next possible moves and follow them up,

```
checkNeighbours(neighbours, path, visited) {
    let validMoves = [];
    neighbours.forEach(potentialMove => {
      if (visited.indexOf(potentialMove.id) < 0) {
        if (potentialMove.state !== 0) {
          validMoves.push(potentialMove);
        }
      }
    });

    if (validMoves.length === 0) {
      return;
    } else {
      let finish = validMoves.filter(cell => cell.state === 3);
      console.log(finish);
      if (finish.length === 1) {
        return path;
      }
    }
    validMoves.forEach(validMove => {
      path.push(validMove);
      visited.push(validMove.id);
      this.checkNeighbours(
        this.getNeighbours(validMove.x, validMove.y),
        path,
        visited
      );
    });
  }
```

I then proceed to try and put this all together and solve the maze,

```
initSolve(maze) {
    let maze = maze;
    let start = [];
    let paths = [];
    let visited = [];
    let current = null;

    maze.forEach(row => {
      row.forEach(cell => {
        // Is start?
        if ((start.length == 0) & (cell.state == 2)) {
          start.push(cell);
          visited.push(cell.id);
          current = cell;
        }
      });
    });
    let result = this.checkNeighbours(
      this.getNeighbours(current.x, current.y),
      paths,
      visited
    );
    console.log("test", result);
  }
```

My question is the following. Using this very contrived and simple maze configuration, I have stepped through the code and can confirm that my

```
checkNeighbours()
```

function will recursively arrive at the end. At that point, the function has an array (the variable *path*) that contains the correct steps through the maze. How do I return this *branch*, if you will, from the recursive call? What happens when there are multiple *branches*?
The only thing I can think of is using a global variable, but I feel this can not be correct.

This is ripped from a React frontend , here is runnable code:

```
let rawMaze = [
            [0, 1, 3],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [2, 1, 0]
        ]
        let maze = []


        function constructMaze() {
            let counter = 0
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                maze[i] = [];
                for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    const Cell = {
                        x: j,
                        y: i,
                        state: rawMaze[i][j],
                        id: counter
                    };
                    maze[i].push(Cell);
                    counter++
                }
            }
        }

        function getNeighbours(x, y) {
            let maze = this.maze;
            let neighbours = [];
            maze.forEach(row => {
                row.forEach(cell => {
                    if (
                        (cell.x == x && cell.y == y + 1) ||
                        (cell.x == x && cell.y == y - 1) ||
                        (cell.y == y && cell.x == x + 1) ||
                        (cell.y == y && cell.x == x - 1)
                    ) {
                        neighbours.push(cell);
                    }
                });
            });

            return neighbours;
        }

        function checkNeighbours(neighbours, path, visited) {
            let validMoves = [];
            neighbours.forEach(potentialMove => {
                if (visited.indexOf(potentialMove.id) < 0) {
                    if (potentialMove.state !== 0) {
                        validMoves.push(potentialMove);
                    }
                }
            });

            if (validMoves.length === 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                let finish = validMoves.filter(cell => cell.state === 3);
                console.log(finish);
                if (finish.length === 1) {
                    return path;
                }
            }
            validMoves.forEach(validMove => {
                path.push(validMove);
                visited.push(validMove.id);
                this.checkNeighbours(
                    this.getNeighbours(validMove.x, validMove.y),
                    path,
                    visited
                );
            });
        }

        function initSolve() {
            let maze = constructMaze()
            let start = [];
            let paths = [];
            let visited = [];
            let current = null;

            maze.forEach(row => {
                row.forEach(cell => {
                    // Is start?
                    if ((start.length == 0) & (cell.state == 2)) {
                        start.push(cell);
                        visited.push(cell.id);
                        current = cell;
                    }
                });
            });
            let result = this.checkNeighbours(
                this.getNeighbours(current.x, current.y),
                paths,
                visited
            );
            console.log("test", result);
        }
```

Comment: can you add runable code?

Comment: Good point! Thanks! I added runnable code

Comment: "*What happens when there are multiple branches?*" - you need to decide. Simply `return`ing a value doesn't work well when there are actually multiple values. So what end result do you expect? An array of branches maybe?

Comment: Yes, an array of branches is what I am looking for. After the function execution, I would loop through the array and pick the shortest one for example. Can this only be done with a more top-level variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I recommend adding another class:

```
function Path() {
    this.isValidPath = false;
    this.pathArray = [];
}
```

And also reworking the `checkNeighbours` function to rename/include these parameters?

```
checkNeighbours(neighbours, paths, currentPathIndex, visited)
```

This way, `paths` could contain an array of `Path` classes, and you could set the `isValidPath` flag to true when you found a valid path (assuming you want to also include invalid and valid paths in the array). This would allow you to return all paths (branches). Each branch would be in the `paths` array at position `currentPathIndex`, which you'd increment in the code once one path is complete and you want to start searching for another path.

Also, currently the `checkNeighbours` function appears to do a breadth first search for valid moves. Perhaps if you reworked it into more of a depth-first traversal, then you could add each valid path (and exclude any invalid paths) to the paths array you return.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. With regard to what type of search it is, you tell me! I didn't really pick an algorithm, I just thought about how I would naively solve this and then implemented it.

I will try to add the class. At the moment, I don't understand why I would need currentPathIndex.

Comment: For the `currentPathIndex`, I was thinking the line `path.push(validMove);` will have to change to something like `paths[currentPathIndex].pathArray.push(validMove);` instead. And then you'll increment it for the next path. But that's just one way of doing it. I'm sure you can do it another way without needing this variable.